# Can a charmed Beast Master ranger's Primal Companion attack the charmer?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, conditions, animal-companions, charmed

If a Beast Master ranger has a Primal Companion, and the ranger is charmed, can the charmed ranger instruct their Primal Companion to attack the charmer?

I ask this because the Primal Companion feature states that a ranger must use their bonus action (or one of their attacks) to have their Primal Companion take the Attack option. I believe that would count as a harmful effect against the charmer, so I'm wondering if that's the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 15):

The [Charmed condition](https://5e.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#charmed) says:

> A charmed creature can’t attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.

Your Ranger's ability to command their companion to attack the charmer is, well, a harmful ability. By the plain reading of the condition, they are unable to do that.